# docker container ldconfig shared libraries removed but application still works

Tags: docker, containers, shared-libraries

I have a container that works. but it shouldn't.. let me explain...
container starts with use of a Dockerfile with application starting in /opt/app
with [ ENTRYPOINT /opt/app ]
It originally did not work. I changed the ENTRYPOINT to /bin/bash
and was able to debug it and add needed shared library conf file to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ run ldconfig
and then the application works. all good.
But the functionality I expect if I remove it does not work in the container.

Does anyone know of a reason for this ?

Thank you

In a Linux VM when I removed the conf file from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and run ldconfig again the application does not work, this is as expected.
But this does not occur in the docker container.
It works to add shared libraries but not to remove them.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  More details on what exactly you're doing would be helpful.  What's in the image; what are you doing in the interactive shell (and why)?